# Git: Merge Remote Branch into Remote Master?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to figure out the standard way of using Git to merge a remote branch (`origin/develop`) into my remote master branch (`origin/master`).  I've taken a look at this:

[Git - How to merge a remote branch into remote master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972399/git-how-to-merge-a-remote-branch-into-remote-master)

which suggests that I do the following:

1) Make changes on my local `develop` branch

2) Commit changes on `develop`

3) Merge local `develop` into local `master`

4) Push local `master` to `origin/master`

Here's my question:  Do I never need to merge one remote branch into another?  Is the standard approach just to keep updating a remote branch like `origin/develop` to save progress, ultimately merging those changes into local `master` and pushing to `origin/master`?

I think this will mess up the log of commits for my remote, as I'll eventually delete the remote branches I used to keep track of my local `develop` progress...

Thanks!

Comment: I am unsure whether there is a definite answer to your question... I'd say it depends on which workflow you would like to choose, if you work alone or collaboratively with a large team, etc. Actually, there exists two widespread git workflows, the Git Flow and the GitHub Flow: FYI I gave an overview of these two workflows (along with related concepts) in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49581009).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8274943/7976758

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I never need to merge one remote branch into another?

In fact, you *can't* do that.  Well, you can, sort of, but—well, it's confusing.  Let's back up. :-)

Git has some rather poor terminology here.  The word *branch* is ambiguous.  Once you get used to all of its different meanings, it's not such a bad name: one says "work on branch X" or "checkout out branch Y" and we all know what we meant, but getting to that point is hard.  For more about this, see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  But start with this: Git is mostly about *commits*.  Branch names come in later.

#### Commits and branch names

The most basic way that Git (and you) can find a commit is by its hash ID, which is guaranteed to be unique to that particular commit.  But these hash IDs appear to be random: `26e47e261` comes before `8b026edac` but `1f1cddd55` comes after either of those, for instance (these are actual commits in the Git repository for Git).  Names, like branch names and remote-tracking names, are there to let Git—and you—*find* the commits.  Each such name remembers exactly one hash ID.

Almost every commit also remembers one or two hash IDs.  These are the *parent* commits of that commit.  Git can string these various hash IDs, starting with the one stored in a name and working backwards, into chains of commits:

```
A  <-B  <-C   <--master
```

The name `master` remembers the hash ID of commit `C`, which remembers the hash ID of commit `B`, which remembers the hash ID of commit `A`.  `A` is the very first commit (in this tiny repository with only three commits) so it has *no* parent and thus ends the chain.

The process of adding a new commit consists of writing out the new commit, using the current end-of-branch-chain hash ID as its parent, and then making the *name* point to the new commit:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

(It's easier not to draw the internal arrows, which always point backwards by definition and—unlike branch names—can never be changed once made, so I generally don't draw them.)

#### Remote-tracking names

When you work with a Git repository, you generally start by getting all the commits from some other, existing, Git repository.  The *other* Git is using *its* branch names to find these commits.  Your Git collects those commits, but your Git is going to give you *your* branch names, independent of theirs.  So your Git needs some *other* names—names that are not *branch* names—in order to find their commits.  You clone their repository, and your Git *renames* their `master` to your `origin/master`—a *remote-tracking name* or *remote-tracking branch name*, which some people call a *remote branch name*.<sup>1</sup>

After the initial clone, which creates `origin/*`, a `git fetch origin` will call up the same URL—saved from when you did the clone—to talk to the same Git, collect from it any new commits it may have, and update all your remote-tracking names to match their branch names.  So your remote-tracking names *automatically follow* their branch names.  That's their main purpose: to remember which commit *their* branch names are remembering.

---

<sup>1</sup>"Remote branch name" is probably the worst of all these phrases, not that any of them are great, because Git uses the word *remote* to refer to a name like `origin` that you can use to identify the *other* Git repository.  So if you were to go to the Git at the URL listed under your `remote.origin.url`, and ask it about its branches, you'd get *their* `master`, *their* `develop`, and so on.  These are the branch names on the remote: the remote's branch names.  Each one must necessarily be a remote branch name.  But they're not in *your* Git, which has instead names like `origin/master` and `origin/develop`.  I think calling `origin/master` a *remote-tracking name* is the best of these ambiguous phrases: it's *your* name for *their* (`origin`'s) `master`.

---

#### Creating a branch name from another name

The last step of `git clone` is generally `git checkout master`.<sup>2</sup>  Your Git doesn't *have* a `master` yet, so your Git prowls through all the remote-tracking names it has (it just made them)—`origin/develop` and `origin/master` and so on—and finds their `origin/master`.  This points to some specific commit, so your Git now *creates* your `master`, pointing to the *same* commit:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
          \
           E   <-- origin/develop
```

If you now run `git checkout develop`, that creates your own `develop`, pointing to the same commit as `origin/develop`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master, origin/master
          \
           E   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

Note that `HEAD` is attached to one of your branch names—that's how Git knows which branch you're on, when you make a new commit.

Let's say you add your own commit to your own `master`, by doing `git checkout master` and doing some work.  This creates a new, unique-hash-ID commit, and makes your `master` point to this new commit:

```
           F   <-- master (HEAD)
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- origin/master
          \
           E   <-- develop, origin/develop
```

This particular example does not use `git merge`, which has its own set of complications (I don't want to get into the details here), but the point is simple enough: **you always do all *your* work on *your own* branches.**  When you have finished this work, you can then run `git push` to:

- send commit(s) to the other Git, as necessary; and then
- ask their Git to set *their* branch name based on what you just sent.

Hence you can now `git push origin master` to send your new commit `F` to them, and ask them to make *their* `master` point to commit `F`.  If they agree to this, your Git records this update so that you now have:

```
           F   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
          /
A--B--C--D
          \
           E   <-- develop, origin/develop
```

---

<sup>2</sup>You can tell your Git to use another name, and if you don't, the other Git tells your Git which name to use, but usually that's `master`.