# What does commit message "Merge branch of 'xxx' https://bitbucket.org/xx/xxx" means?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Currently my team is using BitBucket as code hosting. By default, we do not fast-forward when merging changes.

Sometime when I'm pulling new changes from BitBucket , a new commit appeared like this

[image]

My question is, why this happened in sometime? In most of the time, there is no new commit like this when pulling

Answer (score 0):

If your remote branch has evolved (new commit pushed by other), then a [pull would by default fetch + merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8274988/6309): hence the new merge commit.

If you want to avoid that, [use (since Git 2.6+)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309):

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

Then a regulat pull through Atlassian SourceTree would rebase your local commits on top of the fetch origin/master one, avoiding any new merge commit.